# Can we Use teradata with EntityFramework 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am following database first approach and my db type is tera data. So I  have added tera data through nuget, also added in system ODBC driver. But when creating edmx file through Ado.net entity data model , tera data data source is not showing in options. Can anyone help me with this?  Thanks in advance

Comment: check of they have a data provider to work with ef

Comment: some docs I found, it says it supports. But not working for me. Otherwise I need to use ADO.net

Comment: just out of interest why  teradata